# Filling a spreadsheet template with Apache POI - memory usage

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-io

Dear friends I'm new of java and now I'm working on some modules of a java web app. 
Actually I have to read an template excel file from my classpath, fill it and return the  file filled at the user.

Now I managed this situation in this way:

```
public byte[] processCustomerFile() throws Exception {

    //First way to load
    InputStream  is  = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reportTemplate.xlsx");    
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
    is.close();

    //method wich will fill the file
    fillFile(wb);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(bos);
    return bos.toByteArray();

}
```

My main concern is the memory usage, and the problems that can come out of this.

What are the pros and cons of this method?
Is this a correst way to manage this kind of situation?
Can you suggest me somethings about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would configure a working queue. This method would insert a task into the queue. On the other side there would be a single threaded worker (or worker with fixed number of threads) consuming the tasks, producing results and saving them in a designated location from the task itself. User either via polling from the browser or on the next request would check if the task has been completed. If so, it would pick up the result, send it back in the response or send back a link to the browser showing the location where the resulting Excel document could be downloaded from.

Controlled number of working threads would allow for efficient usage of memory and CPU.

Comment: Can you give me an example of your suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at the jBoss quickstart projects: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart - Look for projects defining a JMX queue.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new of java and JMX can you tell me the The project to look at, sorry but I'm a little confused

Comment: I'm giving a look at what you told me, but which could be the trouble adopting my solution